# Has offset changed, I am going crazy here

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't think detailed description is needed, picture says it all, I have searched on many websites, and I am just getting more and more frustrated.

I am using excel **2016** if that matters.

Can someone help me on this issue, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

image of error

Comment: Did you _Ctrl+Shift+Enter_?

Comment: Yes, it returns the value 120,000,000, which means it completely ignores width and height arguments.

Comment: highlight a range that is 2x2, then put the formula in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter. 2016 does not spill, so you must highlight the range into which you want to place the results of the array formula, so that all cells get a formula automatically put in.

Comment: Jesus.... Thank you so much. Why this isnt mentioned anywhere? for example at 8:38 mark https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYEStSvsYws

Comment: Your mentioned tutorial is for Excel 2019 not Excel 2016

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I didnt catch that. Also didn't think such change can happen between the versions.

Comment: But what I see the behavior should be same as in `Excel 2013-Excel 2021` [read here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#ID0EBBJ=Office_2013_-_2021), as already mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir, you need to select the array of ranges.

Comment: Checked video again and I think CSE is not even used so possibly newer Excel version is used. Using 3rd party tutorials comes with drawbacks

Comment: I have not checked the video, I will see it, But the behavior will be same from `Excel 2013 till Excel 2021` as far I remember, `Excel 2019` also needs to do the same way as is mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir

Comment: I just watched the video, MVP Deb Asbhy who is narrating, she is using `MS365` but what i am trying to say what @ScottCraner Sir suggested is applicable from `Excel 2013 To Excel 2021` not only for `Excel 2016` also I think the method will be same for `Excel 2010`. otherwise it will show `#VALUE!` error. unless one is wrapping with someother functions like `SUM()` or `MAX()` or `INDEX()` etc as per requirement

Comment: @user11222393 With the advent of Dynamic Array formulas and the ability to spill that was released in Office 365 we no longer need to use CSE or choose multiple cells.  so most likely the video is using that version.  there are large differences being made that the older versions do not have.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, True, in the video the narrator is using `MS365`. I have seen other videos of her. Saw this one from a different youtube user profile. And it was posted 3years back--`Oct 27, 2020  Microsoft Excel 2019 Training Tutorials for MS Excel 2019` but they wrongly tagged Excel 2019

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I understand that :) OP uses Excel 2016, mentioned tutorial is tagged under Excel 2019 while 365 is actually used. Answer to OP's "I am using excel 2016 if that matters." is yes, in this case it really matters.